# How to sort a disjoint sublist?

Tags: algorithm, list

Let's say I have the following list: [2, 1, 4, 6, 3, 7]. I also have some method that sorts any list. However, I want to perform a sort across only elements at indices 1, 2, & 4, i.e. the sublist [1, 4, 3]. Sorting across this sublist produces [1, 3, 4]. How can get the original list such that I only sort across indices 1, 2, and 4, i.e., [2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 7]?

Comment: I liked the question so did a version on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_disjoint_sublist). Answers so far, (and it is early), are in J and in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use an extra level of indirection. For example, create a list (here meaning just some linear collection, not necessarily a linked list) of the indexes of the three elements you want to sort, and code to do comparison/swapping through that layer of indirection.

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking, if your language supports pointers you can create an array of pointers to the elements you want and call a sort to the contents of the pointers.

Comment: Or, if you're indexing, and the mapping is simple, you can make a simple index function that converts sublist index to an underlying array index.

Comment: If using the functional kind of list, you can save the original indices of the elements of your sublist, then use them to merge the sorted sublist back into the original.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by Jerry Coffin, here's the solution in Java for those who are interested:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ExtendedSubList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
{
    protected final List<E> parent;
    protected final int[] indices;

    public static <E> List<E> subList(final List<E> parent, int ... indices)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("parent == null");
        if (indices == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("indices == null");
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
            if (!(0 <= indices[i] && indices[i] < parent.size()))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("index %d (at position %d) is not in bounds", indices[i], i));
        Arrays.sort(indices);
        return new ExtendedSubList(parent, indices);
    }

    protected ExtendedSubList(List<E> parent, int[] indices)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.indices = indices;
    }

    public E get(int index)
    {
        return parent.get(indices[index]);
    }
    public int size()
    {
        return indices.length;
    }

    public E set(int index, E element)
    {
        return parent.set(indices[index], element);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 1, 4, 6, 3, 7);
Collections.sort(ExtendedSubList.subList(list), 1, 2, 4);
```

The resulting list would produce: `[2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 7]`.

Comment: I'd post this as an edit to your question (after it) instead of as another answer. Oh, and accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code does the job. It may differ from Jerry Coffins accepted answer as rather than sorting through indirection it extracts the values, sorts, then inserts them back.

```
data    = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
indices = sorted([1,2,4])
values  = [data[i] for i in indices] # [6, 5, 3]
values.sort()                        # [3, 5, 6]
for index, value in zip(indices, values):
    data[index] = value
print (data)                         # [7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 1, 0]
```

1. The original indices should be
   sorted for things to work.
2. The corresponding values are
   extracted.
3. The values are sorted.
4. The for loop puts the sorted values
   back into the original array.